# Can I enforce explicitly-initialized array size at compile-time with gcc extensions?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

**Can I force GCC to throw a warning or error at compile-time if the number of elements in a certain explicitly-initialized C array is not equal to a certain value?**

Consider the following simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum my_enum {
    MY_ENUM_FIRST,
    MY_ENUM_SECOND,
    MY_ENUM_THIRD,
    MY_ENUM_COUNT
};

// indexable by my_enum
const char *my_enum_names[] = {
    "first",
    "second",
    "third",
};

int main(void) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MY_ENUM_COUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", my_enum_names[i]);
    }
}
```

Unless they are directly adjacent in the code, a developer might not realize that the enum and array must be kept "synchronized" with each other. A developer may add an entry to the enum but not to the array (or vice-versa) and therefore expose an out-of-bounds vulnerability.

**Can I add some sort of pragma or attribute to the definition of `my_enum_names` so that if its size is not equal to `MY_ENUM_COUNT`, the compiler will throw a warning or error?**

Some clarifications:

- I am referring specifically to arrays which are explicitly initialized, meaning their size is known at compile-time.
- I am referring specifically to the GCC compiler, including compiler extensions.

I swear I've done this before, possibly using one of GCC's `__attribute__` extensions, but now I can't find any documentation on any feature that does what I want.

Comment: Are you looking or GCC's `-Warray-bounds` compile flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_Static_assert(sizeof my_enum_names / sizeof *my_enum_names == MY_ENUM_COUNT,
    "my_enum_names is the wrong size.");
```

Prior to the addition of `_Static_assert` to the language, you could force errors in these situations with declarations such as:

```
extern char my_enum_namesIsTheWrongSize[1];
extern char my_enum_namesIsTheWrongSize[sizeof my_enum_names / sizeof *my_enum_names == MY_ENUM_COUNT];
```

If the test in the latter were false, it would attempt to declare an array with zero elements, which is an error itself, but, just in case the compiler does not report zero-size arrays, also conflicts with the preceding declaration, and so it should generate an error message.

Comment: it's strange that i am having trouble finding any real, official documentation on `_Static_assert` from gcc. it looks like `static_assert` is part of C11, and glibc implements it in `assert.h`, and gcc itself has supported `_Static_assert` since 4.6, but i don't see any manpages or even a document describing the arguments and expected behavior of either variant of the function.

Comment: gcc/tcc/clang all accept zero-sized arrays without error. You usually want to turn the bool the zero into a negative int to really fail the compilation.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow: It is not a GCC extension. It is a part of standard C since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
const char *my_enum_names[MY_ENUM_COUNT] = { ... };
```

Then the array will always contain enough elements, but some may be `NULL` which you then need to add check for instead. It's still better than risking going out of bounds.

Also, with the above, if you remove enumerations then the compiler will warn you about to many initializers if you forget to update the array initialization.